# Best server side technology with Adobe Flex as UI

Tags: java, apache-flex

I am new to web technologies. I along with my friends want to develop a web application. There is one guy in our team who knows Flex technology. I would like to use Java Springs framework at the back end. 
The web application caters to students a Music school. And for the same reason we chose Flex for UI since the application needs to be flashy and rich in graphics. 
The application allows students to create profiles and interact with the teacher. Eventually we want to add Online Music classes feature with online payment gateway integrated. 
Kindly guide me which are the suitable technologies to use at the back end. Also let me know if **SpringFlex** with **BlazeDS integration** is a good combination with **Adobe Flex**.

Comment: There is no objective answer to this question; any back-end tech that can be used to expose services is fine. If you're new to web technologies, the more abstractions you layer on those services the (a) longer it will take to learn, and (b) more difficult it will be to debug. Get something working, then abstract.

Answer (score 0):

For a small project like this you can really use the Spring + Spring BlazeDS Integration and BlazeDS. But I would recommend to use at least some Flex framework on the frontent like Cairngorm3 + Parsley or other simple ones (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_framework.html) not to end with some cowboy codings there. Another solution could be GraniteDS which is similar to BlazeDS.

Comment: Thanks! :) i am currently using Adobe Flex with Parsley, Spring and BlazeDS integration with Apache TomCat as server and MySQL as DB. Finding it hard to figure out things. The problem I am facing here is BlazeDS TurnKey supports TomCat6 but Springs3 plugin on eclipse(which is the latest available) does not support TomCat6. It only supports TomCat7. Kindly help me with a good tutorial which i can refer.